# Limitation for Excel file

Tags: asp.net, .net, excel, ssis

I have .net application which uses SSIS package to download the data in excel sheet, When I tried to download data in excel from .net application it download only 500kb data. However when running the package manually in SSIS it downloads all the data
So just want to know that is their any limitation of any dll or any additional configuration which needs to be done?

Comment: Do a web search for Excel Specifications and Limits for your Excel version

Comment: To restate, you have an application that runs an ssis package. Your SSIS does not perform as expected in that context. If you use the MS supplied applications (dtexec or Visual Studio's dtsdebug) the package performs as expected?

Comment: yes. When I am running the package SSDT tool package is working as expected